# Where the system call function “sys_getpid” is located in the linux kernel?

Tags: operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm searching the "**getpid**" function in the kernel, however i could not find the actual function.

It should be something like this:

```
asmlinkage long sys_getpid(void)
{
return current-> tgetid;
}
```

All I can find is system call tables, not the actual implementation of this system call.

Kernel version is: **3.0.20**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual definition is in `kernel/timer.c`:

```
/**
 * sys_getpid - return the thread group id of the current process
 *
 * Note, despite the name, this returns the tgid not the pid.  The tgid and
 * the pid are identical unless CLONE_THREAD was specified on clone() in
 * which case the tgid is the same in all threads of the same group.
 *
 * This is SMP safe as current->tgid does not change.
 */
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(getpid)
{
    return task_tgid_vnr(current);
}
```

`task_tgid_vnr` is a static inline in `include/linux/sched.h`.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm still having trouble to find this file. There are lots of timer.c in different directories (arch) . Which one do i need to look at it?

Comment: `kernel_source_dir/kernel/timer.c`, as said above.

Comment: there is no such directory in the root directory of kernel_source_dir in kernel 3.0.20. i have also 2.6.32.56 and i can see this timer.c file in the directory you said, but again i could not find such directory named kernel in the root in 3.0.20.

Comment: There is such a directory in the following versions at least: linux-3.0.3-gentoo/kernel/timer.c
linux-3.1.0-gentoo/kernel/timer.c
linux-3.1.4-gentoo/kernel/timer.c
linux-3.1.5-gentoo/kernel/timer.c
linux-3.1.6-gentoo/kernel/timer.c
linux-3.2.1-gentoo/kernel/timer.c
linux-3.2.5-gentoo/kernel/timer.c
 - I believe it is also present in all 2.6 releases. Please make sure you have a full kernel source extract. You can also see the source online e.g. here: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=tree

Comment: Thank you Mat, I think that the kernel that i have, had some missing directories.

Answer (score 1):

I think for newer versions of kernel it can be found here: `kernel/sys.c`.
The same lines as mentioned in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9340934